# Can I Sue the Police?

Tags: united-kingdom

Long story short:

- My son was backed into by a truck earlier this month.
- They left the scene.
- I called the police, they showed, up I wrote a statement and everything.
- My son later was in the hospital complaining of pain and has had a few visits since.
- I reached out to the officer, never heard back.
- I went to the police department today and found out that the officer did not fill out a MVA or anything and in his dispatch report he said no crime was committed and no charges were filed when my son was injured and I told the officer that I wanted to press charges against the person that hit my son.

Comment: Why are you asking illiterate questions - both in terms of the English language and grasp of the law - while at the same time you list "We are a legal firm..." in your profile?

Comment: Maybe he's trying to drum up business.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Well sported, and quite frightening that OP would give people paid legal advice.

Comment: Why a are you using terms like Truck, MVA, Police Department and dispatch report that are not used in Britain if this is tagged United Kingdom?

Answer (score 4):

A traffic accident is often not a crime even when someone is injured. So suing the police is unlikely to get you anywhere. You can get a lawyer and ask what your chances are to sue the driver who is the person who actually caused the injury, not the police.

Comment: +1 for _sue the driver who is the person who actually caused the injury, not the police_, although a crime was committed as the driver failed to stop (Road Traffic Act 1988, s.170(4) ).